# Longest common subsequence implementation-python

Tags: python, lcs

I have implemented the longest common subsequence problem as instructed in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnWqLAI3TKs). It just execute first set of code and produces an empty list. What is wrong with this implementation?

```
def lcs_recursive(xlist,ylist):
    if not xlist or ylist:
        return []
    x,xs,y,ys, = xlist[0],xlist[1:],ylist[0],ylist[1:]
    if x == y:
        return [x] + lcs_recursive(xs,ys)
    else:
        return max(lcs_recursive(xlist,ys),lcs_recursive(xs,ylist),key=len)



s1 = 'abc'
s2 = 'aeb'

print lcs_recursive(s1,s2)
```

Comment: Why not use google before posting it here?http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#Recursion_7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if not xlist or ylist:` will evaluate as `if (not xlist) or (ylist)` and as such if you pass in something Truthy (like a non-empty list) to `ylist` it will always evaluate to True. You probably want:

```
if not xlist or not ylist:
    return []
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
if not all([xlist, ylist]):
    return []
```

Comment: Oh..I didn't notice it. Thanks.