# How to find the longest common substring of multiple strings?

Tags: python, string

I am writing a python script where I have multiple strings.

For example:

```
x = "brownasdfoersjumps"
y = "foxsxzxasis12sa[[#brown"
z = "thissasbrownxc-34a@s;"
```

In all these three strings, they have one sub string in common which is `brown`. I want to search it in a way that I want to create a dictionary as:

```
dict = {[commonly occuring substring] => 
           [total number of occurrences in the strings provided]}
```

What would be the best way of doing that? Considering that I will have more than 200 strings each time, what would be an easy/efficient way of doing it?

Comment: See [Longest common subsequence implementation-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930671/longest-common-subsequence-implementation-python).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My question is quite different from what you commented. He is trying to compare only two strings which is pretty simple where as I need to use multiple strings to find a common element which occurs more than once.

Comment: The naïve way would be to pick the shortest word and search for all its ngrams of increasing size in all the other strings.

Comment: [longest common subsequence for multiple sequences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752208/longest-common-subsequence-for-multiple-sequences)

Comment: @Elisha512 what do you mean by commonly occuring substring ? Do you want all the substrings which are common in all the strings provided ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a relatively optimised naïve algorithm. You first transform each sequence into a set of all its ngrams. Then you intersect all sets and find the longest ngram in the intersection.

```
from functools import partial, reduce
from itertools import chain
from typing import Iterator


def ngram(seq: str, n: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    return (seq[i: i+n] for i in range(0, len(seq)-n+1))


def allngram(seq: str) -> set:
    lengths = range(len(seq))
    ngrams = map(partial(ngram, seq), lengths)
    return set(chain.from_iterable(ngrams))


sequences = ["brownasdfoersjumps",
             "foxsxzxasis12sa[[#brown",
             "thissasbrownxc-34a@s;"]

seqs_ngrams = map(allngram, sequences)
intersection = reduce(set.intersection, seqs_ngrams)
longest = max(intersection, key=len) # -> brown
```

While this might get you through short sequences, this algorithm is extremely inefficient on long sequences. If your sequences are long, you can add a heuristic to limit the largest possible ngram length (i.e. the longest possible common substring). One obvious value for such a heuristic may be the shortest sequence's length.

```
def allngram(seq: str, minn=1, maxn=None) -> Iterator[str]:
    lengths = range(minn, maxn) if maxn else range(minn, len(seq))
    ngrams = map(partial(ngram, seq), lengths)
    return set(chain.from_iterable(ngrams))


sequences = ["brownasdfoersjumps",
             "foxsxzxasis12sa[[#brown",
             "thissasbrownxc-34a@s;"]

maxn = min(map(len, sequences))
seqs_ngrams = map(partial(allngram, maxn=maxn), sequences)
intersection = reduce(set.intersection, seqs_ngrams)
longest = max(intersection, key=len)  # -> brown
```

This may still take too long (or make your machine run out of RAM), so you might want to read about some optimal algorithms (see the link I left in my comment to your question).

**Update**

To count the number of strings wherein each ngram occurs

```
from collections import Counter
sequences = ["brownasdfoersjumps",
             "foxsxzxasis12sa[[#brown",
             "thissasbrownxc-34a@s;"]

seqs_ngrams = map(allngram, sequences)
counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(seqs_ngrams))
```

`Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, so its instances have similar interfaces:

```
print(counts)
Counter({'#': 1,
         '#b': 1,
         '#br': 1,
         '#bro': 1,
         '#brow': 1,
         '#brown': 1,
         '-': 1,
         '-3': 1,
         '-34': 1,
         '-34a': 1,
         '-34a@': 1,
         '-34a@s': 1,
         '-34a@s;': 1,
         ...
```

You can filter the counts to leave substrings occurring in at least `n` strings: `{string: count for string, count in counts.items() if count >= n}`

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: there is one more thing. It gives me the longest element but what if I want to find all elements that occur more than once and add their occurance number to a dictionary as [sequence] => [occurence] ? Would you be able to suggest something o that?

Comment: @Elisha512 since that is another, SO policies recommend to start a new post. I would gladly help you with that, though.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! But I am asking about the second part of my question. Please see my question where I mention about adding to the dictionary. If you can just help me with it, that would be epic!

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Comment: Wow man, I can't avoid to acknowledge the beauty in your implementation.  Great code. Thanks a lot for sharing

Comment: @EliKorvigo I know this is an old post, but it was just of use to me and I wanted to note you are missing out intersections that go to the full length of a string. It should be lenghts = range(len(seq)+1), I believe.

Comment: Thaks for your solution, thats great. When i use with long and multiple sequences, opration is killed. How can we avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a straightforward method to get the common sub sequences from multiple strings. Although the code can be further optimised.

```
import itertools
 
def getMaxOccurrence(stringsList, key):
    count = 0
    for word in stringsList:
        if key in word:
            count += 1
    return count

def getSubSequences(STR):
    combs = []
    result = []
    for l in range(1, len(STR)+1):
        combs.append(list(itertools.combinations(STR, l)))

    for c in combs:
        for t in c:
            result.append(''.join(t))
    return result

def getCommonSequences(S):
    mainList = []
    for word in S:
        temp = getSubSequences(word)
        mainList.extend(temp)
    
    mainList = list(set(mainList))
    mainList = reversed(sorted(mainList, key=len))
    mainList = list(filter(None, mainList))

    finalData = dict()

    for alpha in mainList:
        val = getMaxOccurrence(S, alpha)
        if val > 0:
            finalData[alpha] = val

    finalData = {k: v for k, v in sorted(finalData.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

    return finalData


stringsList = ['abc', 'cab', 'dfab', 'xz']
seqs = getCommonSequences(stringsList)
print(seqs)
```