# Common string match in pandas data frame

Tags: python, string, pandas

Having a pandas data frame containing several (unix) path entries, which feature a common root.

**Note**: root is defined as the shortest possible path existing in the list, e.g.: foo/bar for foo/bar and foo/bar/baz, as foo/bar.
*Not as expected foo for foo/bar and foo/bar/baz*, as foo is not present in the given column `path`.

How can one efficiently determine the root for each entry?

**Creating sample data**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

sample_data = StringIO(
    """
path
foo/bar/baz
foo/bar
foo/bar/baz/foo1
foo/baz
another/path
another/path/one/more/level
another/path/one
"""
)

df = pd.read_csv(sample_data)
df["root"] = "None" #prepare a column for the root
```

The resulting data frame (`df`) looks like this:

```
    path                        root
0   foo/bar/baz                 None
1   foo/bar                     None
2   foo/bar/baz/foo1            None
3   foo/baz                     None
4   another/path                None
5   another/path/one/more/level None
6   another/path/one            None
```

**The required output**

```
    path                        root
0   foo/bar/baz                 foo/bar 
1   foo/bar                     foo/bar
2   foo/bar/baz/foo1            foo/bar
3   foo/baz                     foo/baz
4   another/path                another/path
5   another/path/one/more/level another/path
6   another/path/one            another/path
```

**What I used**

```
for i, d in df.iterrows():
    df.root = np.where(df.path.str.contains(d.path), d.path, df.root)
```

The output is correct. However, I would like to avoid looping over individual entries in the `df`.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40556491/how-to-find-the-longest-common-substring-of-multiple-strings

Comment: what's your "root" definition? (how do you define it)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks for pointing this out, my definition is different than one would expect. Edited.