# How to aggregate two rows with the same value in another column?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

| name | cluster |
| --- | --- |
| 'sock' | 1 |
| 'graceful' | 2 |
| 'disgrace' | 2 |
| 'fixture' | 3 |
| 'winnow' | 4 |
| 'window' | 4 |

and a function `common_substring` that takes in two **strings** and returns the longest common substring.

I want to return

| name | cluster |
| --- | --- |
| 'sock' | 1 |
| 'grace' | 2 |
| 'fixture' | 3 |
| 'win' | 4 |

I know I'm supposed to group by cluster, but I'm struggling with how to aggregate and apply a function that takes two values.

Comment: Whats happens if there are 3 values per group ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with aggregate function for pass function if length of group is not `1`, then pass all values in column in list:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40556491
from functools import partial, reduce
from itertools import chain
from typing import Iterator

def ngram(seq: str, n: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    return (seq[i: i+n] for i in range(0, len(seq)-n+1))

def allngram(seq: str) -> set:
    lengths = range(len(seq)+1)
    ngrams = map(partial(ngram, seq), lengths)
    return set(chain.from_iterable(ngrams))

def func(x):
    seqs_ngrams = map(allngram, x.tolist())
    intersection = reduce(set.intersection, seqs_ngrams)
    longest = max(intersection, key=len)
    return longest

df['name'] = df['name'].str.strip("'")

df = df.groupby('cluster')['name'].agg(func).reset_index()
print (df)
   cluster     name
0        1     sock
1        2    grace
2        3  fixture
3        4      win
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40556491/how-to-find-the-longest-common-substring-of-multiple-strings.

Comment: @keramat - You are right, aded to answer.

Comment: @jezrael, I did too!

Comment: @keramat - unfortuantely it failed. So add correct solution to my answer.

Comment: @jezrael, I tested it and provided an example too. How does it fail?

Comment: @keramat try data from question.

Comment: @keramat - I use your solution and improve it for working with any length of values per groups.

Comment: @jezrael, I realized. The problem was with unique values and i fixed that. Working with any number of values is an direction, too.

Comment: I generalized the solution for any length.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the @jezrael and [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40556491/how-to-find-the-longest-common-substring-of-multiple-strings):

```
from functools import partial, reduce
from itertools import chain
from typing import Iterator


def ngram(seq: str, n: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    return (seq[i: i+n] for i in range(0, len(seq)-n+1))


def allngram(seq: str) -> set:
    lengths = range(len(seq))
    ngrams = map(partial(ngram, seq), lengths)
    return set(chain.from_iterable(ngrams))


def func(a, b):
    seqs_ngrams = map(allngram, [a,b])
    intersection = reduce(set.intersection, seqs_ngrams)
    longest = max(intersection, key=len)
    return longest

def f(x):
    try:
        return func(x.iat[0], x.iat[1])
    except:
        return 'Unique value'

df = df.groupby('cluster')['name'].agg(f).reset_index()
print (df)
```

Demonstration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['winnow', 'window'], 'cluster':[4,4]})
df = df.groupby('cluster')['name'].agg(f).reset_index()
```

output:

[image]

For, any length input:

```
from functools import partial, reduce
from itertools import chain
from typing import Iterator


def ngram(seq: str, n: int) -> Iterator[str]:
    return (seq[i: i+n] for i in range(0, len(seq)-n+1))


def allngram(seq: str) -> set:
    lengths = range(len(seq)+1)
    ngrams = map(partial(ngram, seq), lengths)
    return set(chain.from_iterable(ngrams))


def func(seq):
    seq=seq.values
    seqs_ngrams = map(allngram, seq)
    intersection = reduce(set.intersection, seqs_ngrams)
    
    longest = max(intersection, key=len)
    return longest

def f(x):
    return func(x)
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['winnow', 'window', 'win', 'sock', 'graceful', 'disgrace','fixture'], 'cluster':[4,4,4,1,2,2,3]})

df = df.groupby('cluster')['name'].agg(f).reset_index()
```

Ooutput:

[image]